# untabify within a rectangular region?

Tags: rectangle

How may I call `untabify` against a rectangular region?

This screenshot illustrates what I am trying to accomplish.  I have a messy mixture of tabs and spaces in the region I have circled.  `untabify` will fix it, but I don't want to eliminate the tabs on the left of each line.  Those are fine.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate? For instance, you could show an example, and what you'd expect as the result.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builtin `untabify` command doesn't support the rectangular region. Here is a new command:

```el
(defun my-untabify (b e)
  "Like `untabify' but support both ordinary and rectangular region."
  (interactive "*r")
  (if (region-noncontiguous-p)
      (apply-on-rectangle
       (lambda (startcol endcol)
         (untabify (progn (move-to-column startcol) (point))
                   (progn (move-to-column endcol) (point))))
       b e)
    (untabify b e current-prefix-arg)))
```

Comment: You could contribute your code to Emacs (even better, using `region-boundaries` so it can even work on non-rectangular non-contiguous regions).

Comment: @Stefan How to create a non-rectangular non-contiguous region as a user? Any other emacs commands support such region? In Emacs 26.2, `region-bounds` is called only two times.

Comment: `region-bounds` is new.  User-level commands to create a non-contiguous region are still waiting for someone to implement them (presumably the `zones.el` package in GNU ELPA could be a good starting point).

Comment: I finally got around to testing this and LGTM.  I'll now go search around to find out how to replace a builtin.  Incidentally, I was not aware of the difference between `C-SPC` and `C-x SPC` until today.  (all the rectangle command I'd tried so far work with regular regions, except the visuals don't match.)